# Unable to download image using Picasso on Android

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to download the following image using Picasso https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/94E7Ti0RTDbA6mGotZw5DA/o.jpg

I can see it fine in a browser. However when I attempt to download it using Picasso, I get an error (a breakpoint in my onError() method gets hit).

This is an extract of my code:

```
final RequestCreator rc = with(context).load(fullImagePath);

if (fit != null && fit) {
    rc.fit();
}

// If no callback listener exists, create one.
if (callbackListener == null) {
    callbackListener = new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            L.p("onSuccess retrieving " + fullImagePath);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            // Something went wrong
            L.p("Error retrieving " + fullImagePath);
        }

    };
}

rc.into(fImageView, callbackListener);
```

I found this: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/500 however it's a bit dated and the OkHttpClient class no longer has the setProtocols() method.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I haven't played with Picasso in some time but try inserting that link as "http" instead of "https" and see if it works or not.

Comment: I'll try, but on the browser it redirects to https

Comment: @SaltySea On the browser it's a 307 Internal Redirect. I'll try in the app

Comment: @SaltySea That seems to have done the trick

Comment: Really? Damn, I guess my memory didn't fail me. I remember running into this problem before and it was because something to do with certificates/signature/security stuff. I'll post it as an answer so this question is wrapped up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting that link as "http" instead of "https" will work.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me for both http and https links.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    String https = "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/94E7Ti0RTDbA6mGotZw5DA/o.jpg";
    String http = "http://www.sunseed.org.uk/projectpack/files/2014/05/Library_1400_800-1200x686.jpg";
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(https)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.me)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

Also be sure you write the below permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

also write the following in build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: I'm using `2.5.2` and definitely have the Internet permission.